# How check FTP anonymous connection

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, terminal, debian

I want to ask about ftp connection in linux,
how can i check the ftp anonymous connection in linux by using terminal?
i use while loop for read vsftpd.conf file, like that

```
 while read line 
   do
    if [ Anonymous_enable=YES ];
       then echo " Accept connection"
    elif [ Anonymous_enable=NO ];
      then echo "Not Accept"
fi
done<vsftpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why are you using while loop but you can use simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=`cat /etc/vsftpd | grep ^anonymous_enable | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $X = "YES" ]]
then
        echo -e "Accept connection\n"
else
        echo -e "Not Accept\n"
fi
```

Output:

```
[root@ftp ~]# sh /tmp/anon_check.sh
Accept connection
```

Comment: don't forget to answer it, if useful.